# How to mirror an image data by OpenGL ES on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

I'm developing a tool on jailbroken device. 
I get a frame buffer by IOSurfaceGetBaseAddress, which give a mirrored data.
So i would like to mirror the image back. It's too slow to reverse it pixel by pixel, so i want to mirror it by OpenGL ES. Any one has this kind of sample code?

Comment: What is the greater goal you are trying to accomplish? How big is the image? Is it really too slow to flip it pixel by pixel? What did you try that was slow?

Comment: for (int i = 0;  i < _h; ++i)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < _w; ++j)
                    {
                        memcpy(data + i * _w * 4 + (_w - 1 - j) * 4,  baseAddr + i * _w * 4 + 4 * j, 4);
                    }
                }

Comment: The device is iPad3, so _w = 2048, _h = 1535. It's really too slow.

Comment: The goal is that I would like to capture the iPad/iPhone Screen and encode it to h264 stream. I have tried UIGetScreenImage, but the efficiency was bad, so i have to use IOSurface.

Answer (score 0):

You can render the back side of texture.
Then, pixels is reversed on horizontal aspect.

Comment: Can you give me any sample code, for i rarely use opengl es.Thanks.